# How can I evaluate the gradient of a function with a vector?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm looking to evaluate the gradient of a function with n variables. If the function had two variables, I could do it like this:

```
x = {x1, x2};
F[x_] := (1 - Part[x, 1])^2 + 100*(Part[x, 2] - Part[x, 1]^2)^2;
gF[a_, b_] := Grad[F[x], x] /. x1 -> a /. x2 -> b;
gF[1, 2]
```

What I want to do is to pass a vector as a parameter to gF. I tried doing like this, but it didn't work:

```
gF[v_] = Grad[F[x], x] /. x -> v;
gF[{1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what you proposed, the replacement rule `x->v` is not expanded as you expect (you want each part of `x` to be replaced by the matching part of `v`) so `Thread` is your friend:

```
x = {x1, x2};
gF2[v_] := Grad[F[x], x] /. Thread[x -> v]
gF2[{1, 2}]
```

As pointed out by Henrik Schumacher, your implicit assumption is that `x` is a symbolic vector (for example you did not assign numerical values to the symbols `xi` before).

Comment: Thanks, man! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a symbolic vector in order to compute the derivative. Here a quick example.

```
F = x \[Function] x.x + x.x^2;
DF = X \[Function] Evaluate@Quiet@Block[{X, XX},
     XX = Array[Part[X, #] &, 5];
     D[F[XX], {XX, 1}]
     ];

DF[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> {5, 16, 33, 56, 85}